# Programmatically added buttons not matching theme

Tags: android

Using Theme.AppCompat in Gingerbread (API 10), programmatically added buttons do not match buttons added through XML. It works fine in all newer APIs, its only an issue with Gingerbread.  [This image shows the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjHr3.png)

Here is the code that adds the buttons:

```
for (int i = 0; i < btnFiles.length; i++) {
        btnFiles[i] = new Button(this);
        btnFiles[i].setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnFiles[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);                         
        btnFiles[i].setId(100 + i);                                     
        btnFiles[i].setText(fileList.get(i).replace(".xml", ""));       
        btnFiles[i].setTag(fileList.get(i));                            
        registerForContextMenu(btnFiles[i]);                            
        btnFiles[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {                          

                Continue(v);        //Start next activity when button is pressed
            }

        });

        l.addView(btnFiles[i]);     
        setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_load_menu));
    }
```

Comment: Did you set any background color on the xml button?

Comment: @GeorgeRappel No, the only things set in the xml for the clear button are id, width, height, gravity, and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a layout file with just the Button and use a LayoutInflater to inflate it.

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... />

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
for (int i = 0; i < btnFiles.length; i++) {
    btnFiles[i] = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, l, false);
    // everything else, except the LayoutParams stuff because that's in the layout file
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It just needed to be cast as a button `btnFiles[i] = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_button, l, false);`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify for anyone passing by, the issue is probably that `<Button>` tags from XML get replaced by instances of `AppCompatButton` and `<item name="buttonStyle">...</item>` (assuming that's what had been used) applies to that. Same thing happens for many other Views.

So, an **alternative possibility** would be either to put both `<item name="buttonStyle">...</item>` and `<item name="android:buttonStyle">...</item>` into the style, so that `Button` and `AppCompatButton` can be combined, which would be **quite a mess**.

Somewhat better option would be to instantiate `AppCompatButton` for the APIs using AppCompat, but using the **XML layout** with just a **single Button** seems like the safest and most portable solution, so **go for that**, assuming you have no reason not to do that.